# генерировать матчи в турнире

Tags: java, алгоритм, spring

Как создавать матчи в турнире
У меня есть турнир, к нему добавляются участники.
Есть матч, который должен состоять из двух участников.
Как выбрать участников с турнира и генерировать по ним матчи.

```
@Entity
public class Participant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "participant_id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nick_name")
    private String nickName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_fk_id")
    private Tournament tournament;
*gets,Sets
```

Tournament

```
@Entity
public class Tournament {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tournament_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tournament", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TournamentMatch> tournamentMatchSet = new HashSet<>();

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tournament", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Participant> participantList = new ArrayList<>();
```

TournamentMatch

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mach")
public class TournamentMatch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "mach_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalDate startTime;

    @Column(name = "finisch_time")
    private LocalDate finischTime;

    private BigDecimal scores;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_fk_id")
    private Tournament tournament;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "participant_two_fk_id")
    private Participant participantTwo;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "participant_one_fk_id")
    private Participant participantOne;
```

я не могу понять алгоритм решения проблемы.

- у меня есть лист с участниками в турнире
- надо распределить их по парам и добавить в матч?
  или  нужно создать метод,которые добавляет только два участника в матч?

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: извините, не заметил,чо не перешел на английскую версию, исправил